# Need to make template tag from simple.tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have following simple template tag which returns list of values.
What I need is rewrite it like template tag, so I could use returning list as variable

```
@register.simple_tag
def show_active_filters(cleaned_filter):
  filter_list = []
  if cleaned_filter:
    if cleaned_filter['checkbox']:
        for key, value in cleaned_filter['checkbox'].items():
            for values in value:
                filter_list.append('%s: %s' % (key, values))
    if cleaned_filter['from_to']:
        for filter_name, filter_values in cleaned_filter['from_to'].items():
            sorted_values = sorted(filter_values.values())
            if len(sorted_values) < 2:
                try:
                    filter_values['from']
                    filter_str = u'%s :  от %s' % (filter_name, sorted_values[0])
                    filter_list.append(filter_str)
                except:
                    filter_str = u'%s :  до %s' % (filter_name, sorted_values[0])
                    filter_list.append(filter_str)
            else:
                filter_str = u'%s : от %s -  до %s' % (filter_name, sorted_values[0], sorted_values[1])
                filter_list.append(filter_str)
  return filter_list
```

The way I tried to do this is following

```
@register.tag(name='show_active_filters')
def do_show_active_filters(parser, token):
  error = False
  try:
    tag_name, cleaned_filter, _as, var_name = token.split_contents()
    if _as != 'as':
        error = True
  except:
    error = True

  if error:
    raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, 'invalid stuff"'
  else:
    return CleanedFilterDictionary(cleaned_filter, var_name)

class CleanedFilterDictionary(template.Node):
  def __init__(self, cleaned_filter, var_name='filter_vals'):
    self.cleaned_filter = cleaned_filter
    self.var_name = var_name

def render(self, context):
    context[self.var_name] = get_active_filters(cleaned_filter)
    return ''

def get_active_filters(cleaned_filter):
  filter_list = []
  if cleaned_filter:
    if cleaned_filter['checkbox']:
        for key, value in cleaned_filter['checkbox'].items():
            for values in value:
                filter_list.append('%s: %s' % (key, values))
    if cleaned_filter['from_to']:
        for filter_name, filter_values in cleaned_filter['from_to'].items():
            sorted_values = sorted(filter_values.values())
            if len(sorted_values) < 2:
                try:
                    filter_values['from']
                    filter_str = u'%s :  от %s' % (filter_name, sorted_values[0])
                    filter_list.append(filter_str)
                except:
                    filter_str = u'%s :  до %s' % (filter_name, sorted_values[0])
                    filter_list.append(filter_str)
            else:
                filter_str = u'%s : от %s -  до %s' % (filter_name, sorted_values[0], sorted_values[1])
                filter_list.append(filter_str)
  return filter_list
```

Can not get how to pass cleaned_filter variable to class instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the [`assignment_tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) decorator instead of `simple_tag` - the rest of your original code should work as is.